# How to populate the CollectionControlDialog that comes up when using the PropertyGrid's CollectionEditor (Extended WPF Toolkit)?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit, propertygrid, collectioneditor

Using a `PropertyGrid` from the `Extended WPF Toolkit`, I need to use a `CollectionEditor`:

```
[Editor(typeof(CollectionEditor), typeof(CollectionEditor))]
public Definition DefTypes { get; set; }
```

But the [`CollectionControlDialog`](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/CollectionControlDialog) that appears when clicking on the `DefTypes` fields has no items to choose from.

So how do I populate this [`CollectionControlDialog`](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/CollectionControlDialog)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CollectionEditor will only show a collection of a certain type of objects. In this case it doesnt look like you are adding the Editor attribute to a collection, but rather to a single object.

See my code below:

```
public class Definition {
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

public class Definitions : List<Definition> {
}
```

Now you will be able to apply the CollectionEditor to the Definitions:

```
[Editor(typeof(CollectionEditor), typeof(CollectionEditor))]
public Definitions DefTypes { get; set; }
```

And it will bring up the CollectionEditor with the properties defined in 'Definition'